Raspberry Pi code error: 'RuntimeError: failed to add edge detection'
My code has been having issues, it is possible I may have to reflash the memory card with new OS since it worked previously on another Rasp Pi Zero 2.
But if anyone can help with this problem so it wont happen again I'd be grateful.
The issue comes with trying to use the function to detect a distance wheel rev change using the code as follows:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#Distance Wheel
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)


def increaserev(channel):
    global counter
    counter += 1
GPIO.add_event_detect(4,GPIO.RISING, callback=increaserev)

This is a snippet of the code that still produces the same error when isolated.
The full error is shown as:
Traceback (most recent call last) :
    File "/home/pi/test.py", line 12, in <module>
        GPIO.add_event_detect(4,GPIO.RISING, callback=increaserev)
RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection

I have tried:

updating
upgrading
changing GPIO pin
disabling 1-wire system


you havent defined counter, so you cannot increase it

Ye this is just an extract from my main code to show the issue, but running this snippet of code doesnt have the error of no counter being defined due to the main issue being reported halting the program before the increaserev can be reached. The issue is with the GPIO.add_event_detect

This question is similar to: RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection - On Raspberrypi. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
